# MSSQLSYSTEMRESOURCE DATABASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

what is mssqlsystemresource database? do we need to copy this while moving form one server to another one?

Answer (score 2):

All system stored procedures, views and functions are stored in the MsSqlSystemResource database. This db is hidden, you can't see it in SSMS but lives in the data directory...should already be on your new server

run this query on the other server

```
select name, filename
 from master..sysaltfiles
where dbid = 32767
```

Answer (score 1):

The system resource database. You should treat it as part of your SQL Server binaries, not as part of your data. You should never copy this file, it is manipulated only by SQL Setup operations. Replacing a resource database is not supported and can render a SQL Server instance unusable.